# HLS Streaming not working on React Libraries

Tags: reactjs, http-live-streaming, video.js, react-player

I was setting up Raspberry Pi 4 to stream video to connected device. So, I used picamera2 for capturing and streaming the video on network. Internally Picamera2 uses ffmpeg to form m3u8 files for hls streaming. Along with picamera2, I used http.server to host static hls files.

I tested out the hls streaming using the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Your title</title>


    <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" controls
      preload="auto"
      data-setup='{}'>
      <source src="http://192.168.1.8:8000/live/stream.m3u8"
        type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>

    <script>
var player = videojs('my_video_1');
player.play();
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

It ran fine. Started streaming video onto other devices.

But I am not able to do the same using react frontend. I am using ReactPlayer in the following code. Tested out with online hls streaming link, it worked out well. But it is not streaming the following RPI stream on the browser. I have also checked out video.js, react-has-player and ReactPlayer worked best on online hls stream and multiple browser.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useContext } from "react";
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import VideoCameraBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VideoCameraBack';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/lazy'
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
// import { UserContext } from "./context/UserContext";

export default function VideoCard({ alerter }) {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.8:8000/live/stream.m3u8"
    return (
        <Card sx={{ height: '820px' }} variant="outlined">
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                    <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: red[500] }} >
                        <VideoCameraBackIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                }
                title={<Typography component="div" variant="h6">
                    Video Stream
                </Typography>}
                subheader="from Camera"
            />
            <CardContent>
                <div >
                    <ReactPlayer
                        playing
                        url={url}
                        controls={true}
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%" />
                </div>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

In this react ui, it keeps on loading and then Please suggest the solution to make react code work!

I have tried multiple libraries related to hls in react and now asking for help. I think I may be doing silly mistake and that's what I am expecting as a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you reach the HLS manifest from the Raspberry PI using the terminal?

Comment: yes, I can reach to manifest through terminal.